# Json page & post request PHP

Tags: php, json, postgresql, post

I have this post URL:

```
$api_url = www.apiurlexample.com
```

I have this request header:

```
Content-Type: application/json
Referer: https://www.apiurlexample.com/111111/category.html?
X-Referer-Url: https://www.apiurlexample.com/111111/category.html?#brands=[2222]
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
```

And I Have this data in the body:

```
   $brands = {\"brands\":[".11112223333."],\"page\":1}
```

I want to create a json page so I can get the data from there:

```
$jsonpage = $this->get_page( $api_url, array ('data' => $brands, 'content-type'=> 'application/json','Referer'=> $referer,'X-Referer-Url'=> $xreferer,'X-Requested-With'=> 'XMLHttpRequest' ) );

$json_decoded = json_decode($jsonpage);
```

But i didn't do something good, can when i debug this json decoded page, its empty? How i can send this request?

Comment: I think it's a bit unclear what you mean by JSON page but have you tried using http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php to debug the issue?

Comment: i want to take data from jsonpage that i want to create, but i did something wworng creating json page

Comment: Also check what `$jsonpage` contains, it might not even be JSON to begin with, for example if the API answered with an error document.

Comment: how i can check that?

Comment: $jsonpage = $this->get_page( $api_url, array ('data' => $brands, 'content-type'=> 'application/json','Referer'=> $referer,'X-Referer-Url'=> $xreferer,'X-Requested-With'=> 'XMLHttpRequest' ) );

Comment: here is the problem